# @Input access to the object loaded from database

Tags: angular

How can I access to object from parent component using @Input() in the child component itself ?

I can't get object if I load it from database. However I can access to the object in the child template.

**UPDATE : templateUrl to template in ParentComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'child-component',
   templateUrl: './child-component.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input object: Object; // return object in template / undefined in component if loaded from database

   ngOnInit(){
      console.log(this.object); // return undefined if object is loaded from database
   }
}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'parent-observation',
   template: `<child-component [object]="object"></child-component>`,
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
   object: Object;

   constructor(private service: Service){}

   ngOnInit(){
     /** 
      this.service.get(id)
          .subscribe((data:Object) => {
              console.log(data); // return object
              this.object = data;
          }); // this works but console.log(this.object) returns undefined
     **/

      this.object = {prop1: 'prop1', prop2: 'prop2'}; // this works and console.log(this.object) returns object
   }
}
```

Comment: `this.service.get(id)` is asynchronous. You won't get its result in child's `ngOnInit`. Please, explain your issue. If `object` is bound in child's view, it will be updated automatically. If it should be used in child's class, use `ngOnChanges` to detect changes in input.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I want use "object" in template and component. In template, it's working, I can display it, but in component (ChildComponent) I can't get and use the object loaded from database. I've updated my initial post.

Comment: @estus it happens because the child component is loaded before the data from the database, rigth ? How to fix it ?

Comment: If the component can be considered a route, route resolver can be used to get data on component init. But a better option is to stick to observables whenever it is possible, i.e. do `this.service.get(id).subscribe(...)` everywhere where `object` is needed.